# How to display data count per category mysql subquery

Tags: mysql

i have table like bellow

```
tbl=province

id_province | province
----------------------
01      Province1
02      Province2
03      Province3
...
...

tbl=grade
id_grade | grade
-----------------
A      elementary       
B      junior
C      senior

tbl.transaction
-----------------------------
code    | id_province   | id_grade
--------------------------------
t1          01             A
t2          01             A
t3          01             A
t4          02             A
t5          03             C
t6          02             B
t7          03             A
```

how i can query if i want to display data like bellow

```
id_province | province  | count of grade A  | count of grade B | count of grade C
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
01             Province1        3                    0              0
02             Province2        1                    1              0
03             Province3        1                    0              1
```

I have try to make query using subquery like bellow, but it's not work :

```
select id_province,(select count(*) from transaction where id_grade='A') as count of grade A,(select count(*) from transaction where id_grade='B') as count of grade B,
    (select count(*) from transaction where id_grade='C') as count of grade C group by id_province
```

moreover, query above show data like bellow :(

```
id_province | province  | count of grade A  | count of grade B | count of grade C
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
01             Province1        3                    0              0
02             Province2        3                    0              0
03             Province3        3                    0              0
```

Any idea how to solve this ?

Comment: Try quoting the values after the `AS` clause.  For example 'count of grade A'.

Comment: yes i've add it. It just will display header of field. my query result wrong value now

Comment: Did any of the answers below help you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using `case`.

```
select
p.id_province,
p.province,
count(case when t.id_grade = 'A' then 1 else null end) as 'count of grade A',
count(case when t.id_grade = 'B' then 1 else null end) as 'count of grade B',
count(case when t.id_grade = 'C' then 1 else null end) as 'count of grade C'
from
province p,
transation t
where
p.id_province = t.id_province
group by p.id_province
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need group by if you query the "province" table.
Try something like this:

```
select p.id_province, p.province,
(select count(*) from transaction t1 where t1.id_grade='A' AND t1.id_province = p.id_province) as 'count of grade A',
(select count(*) from transaction t2 where t2.id_grade='B' AND t2.id_province = p.id_province) as 'count of grade B',
(select count(*) from transaction t3 where t3.id_grade='C' AND t3.id_province = p.id_province) as 'count of grade C'
FROM province p
```

(sql not tested... may have some typos)

Answer (score 0):

I did this in SQL Server.  Note, `transaction` is reserved word.

```
select t.id_province,p.province,
       (select count(*) from [transaction] where id_grade='A' and id_province = t.id_province) as 'count of grade A',
       (select count(*) from [transaction] where id_grade='B' and id_province = t.id_province) as 'count of grade B',
       (select count(*) from [transaction] where id_grade='C' and id_province = t.id_province) as 'count of grade C'
from [transaction] t 
inner join province p on
    p.id_province = t.id_province
group by t.id_province, p.province
```